# IONIC App works well with FirebaseX but when I open my app if I have push notifications, the app delete them

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have mi Ionic app and works well with FirebaseX only in one case, with Android X if I open my app and I have a push notification on notification bar, the app delete it. This doesn't happen with previous versions of Android.
And if I tap the notification (with the app killed) works well and also in foreground and background.
I tested my app with Android 9 and if I open my app and I have a notification, nothing happens with the notification, the app open normally and the notification keeps alive in the notification bar untill I tap it (I wish the same behavior with Androix X)

Comment: can you paste code snippet from app component file.. where you have intialized the push notification. Might be you are clearing notification while app initialize

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rahul, this is the piece of code that you request me:

Comment: initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.creaDatabase();
      this.fcm.grantPermission();
      this.fcm.getToken().then(this.firebaseTokenSuccess).catch(this.firebaseTokenFailure);  
      this.fcm.onMessageReceived().subscribe((data)=>{